# How to perform custom zoomIn() on osm map

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I have an osm map and I have zoomControls on that. I wan to add the zoomIn and zoomOut functionality on that.

How can i achieve this...?

I am trying this..

```
myMapZoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
mapViewO.getController().setZoom(mapViewO.getZoomLevel()+1);
mapViewO.setMultiTouchControls(true);
mapViewO.getController().zoomIn();

}
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

okey,please add follow code:

mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//显示缩放按钮

Comment: Please translate the comment to English and place the code within a code block.

Comment: I want to achieve custom zoom functionality dear, anyway.. I have got this and its working f9.